# Round Up Number Integer in SQL query

Tags: sql, math, rounding

I have a query for round up for my stored procedure like this

```
DECLARE @number int;

SET @number = 918750;

SELECT @number + (100 - @number % 100 )
```

This returns 918800

The correct value to be returned would be 918,800.

But in case @number = 918800 it will change into 918900.

And I want only 2 last digit is round up.

Can I change it into single query only?

Yes if I use

```
SELECT ROUND(918750 , -2) AS RoundValue;
```

it return 918800, but if i use

```
SELECT ROUND(918740 , -2) AS RoundValue;
```

it return 918700, while i need is always round to up so the result i need is 918000

Comment: Just use Floor, SELECT FLOOR(918800 )

Comment: @TBA , i need to always round up the last 2 digit. if i input 918740 it should return 918800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @number int;

SET @number = 918750;
// Solution 1
select @number -(@number % 100)+iif(@number%100!=0,100,0);

//Solution 2
select ceiling(@number/100.00)*100;
```

Comment: if you put SET @number = 918000;
it will return 918100.

Comment: Now I have updated the query

Comment: yeah, this one of the solution thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

if you re using any of Oracle, MySQL, and PostgreSQL, you can use `ROUND()` function.

like this

```sql
SELECT ROUND(918750 , -2)
```

This query will produce 918800 result. `-2` means the last two digits are rounded up.

Comment: indeed, if i input SELECT ROUND(918740 , -2) . it returns 918700, i need it always round up and the result should be 918800

Comment: I used postgresql. so its generated 918800. if you use another db, result can be diffrent. I'm not entirely sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
DECLARE @Number INT = 435667
SELECT CONVERT(INT, 100 * ROUND(@Number / 100.0, 0))
```